# Why does xcode throw this error even though the profiles are set to distribute?

Tags: ios, xcode4, submission

So I am submitting my First App. I have followed various guides and documents to the letter and managed to upload it to the itunes app store one time. It came back as invalid binary relating to an icon path. Fair enough... I applied what I felt was a fix then BANG! Everytime I tried to upload it since then it comes back with an error, this error to be exact.:

> warning: Unable to extract codesigning entitlements from your
>   application.  Please make sure DoorStop is a valid Mach executable
>   that's properly codesigned. (-19050)
>   /Users/jackson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DoorStop-gfwhzvdhgmutfhdhfmqznkcnzmak/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/DoorStop/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/DoorStop.app/DoorStop:
>   invalid signature (code or signature have been modified)
>    - (null)

Now I have a feeling I know what your going to say, you need to make sure its signed with a distribution profile, It is. I created a new one and tried that, i deleted my developer certificate and distribution certificate from the keychain and re-added them....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so just thought I would answer this question since I solved the problem.

On first submission I had done everything correct. However in an attempt to solve the Icon Path invalid binary I got, I had changed the .plist file. Since that point My App would not validate.

This is due to the fact that for some reason, Xcode had duplicated my .plist file. And was creating a new one with the new edits. To avoid this I simply removed one one .plist file and made sure that i edited the original from the Info Area of the Target, instead of doing it manually.

This avoided Xcode getting confused and the App has been successfully submitted. :)