# iOS App Store validation: Unable to extract codesigning entitlements

Tags: iphone, ios, build, archive

Everything about my app was working fine. I need to change the bundle ID, so I change it from what it currently was set at (com.jeffgrimes9.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}) - exactly what was inside the parentheses. The name of my app was hammerhead. I changed the bundle id to com.jeffgrimes9.locationchat and then immediately changed it back to its previous value when I tried running the simulator and nothing happened.

So at the end of the day it was the same value. But now the app doesn't run at all. I have tried restarting Xcode, restarting the iPhone simulator, clearning my DerivedData folder, cleaning the build, copying all folders to a new projects, tried different bundle id values, looked all over the internet...nothing. But I keep getting the same error message when I try to validate my build for App Store submission:

"Unable to extract codesigning entitlements from your application. Please make sure hammerhead is a valid Mach executable that's properly codesigned."

Any ideas?

Comment: What's version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: lock the answer giver in [this post ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863118/why-does-xcode-throw-this-error-even-though-the-profiles-are-set-to-distribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to make sure your certificates are in order. If so, the problem may be a duplicate plist file.

If you modified the bundle ID directly in the *.plist* file, XCode might've created a second *.plist* file with the changes. Try to find it and delete it. Make sure it has the same values only with differences on the edits you might've made.

Next, try to make the modifications you had made before by going to *Targets > Get Info* and modifying the values there (as opposed to manually editing the *.plist* file). [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-iphone-app) explains what values to modify in that screen.